# Is this recursive reference with tuples safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I'm experimenting and wrote this monster:

```
class my_tuple : public std::tuple < std::vector<my_tuple> > {};
```

And it compiles and actually works, it seems. And I find it dodgy because the following doesn't compile:

```
using my_other_tuple = std::tuple < std::vector<my_other_tuple> > ;
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to wrap my head around why my_tuple works and if there's any potential terrible consequences. I'm trying to learn what tuples are all about and what I can/am supposed to do with them. So if anyone would care to comment on that, give some nifty insights, I would appreciate it.

Windows 7 and VS 2013.

Comment: And what do you expect to be returned from `get<0>(my_other_tuple)[0]`, `my_other_tuple` type? and what is that? class inheritance is not the same as a typedef, in the first at least you have to tell what is in the class.

Comment: The tuple doesn't seem to do anything here. The important part is the vector. It would be practically the same as `class my_vector : public std::vector<my_vector> {};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class my_tuple : public std::tuple < std::vector<my_tuple> > {};
```

This is currently undefined behavior because it instantiates a standard library container, `std::vector`, with an incomplete type, `my_tuple`, which does not become complete until the closing `}` of its definition. However, there is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4056.html) to permit instantiating certain standard containers, including `std::vector`, with incomplete types. [Boost.Containers supports incomplete types as well.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types)

```
using my_other_tuple = std::tuple < std::vector<my_other_tuple> > ;
```

This is ill-formed. [dcl.typedef]/p2, emphasis mine:

> A *typedef-name* can also be introduced by an *alias-declaration*. The
>   *identifier* following the `using` keyword becomes a *typedef-name* and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* following the *identifier*
>   appertains to that *typedef-name*. It has the same semantics as if it
>   were introduced by the `typedef` specifier. In particular, it does not
>   define a new type and **it shall not appear in the *type-id***.

Comment: I read in some Boost book that the standard containers are not guarantied to allow recursion, that ones I tried do. The second issue (the typedef) goes beyond that, it is not possible even in principle.

Comment: Incomplete type. That's the sort of answer I was looking for. Thank you. I knew something was up and I just wasn't seeing it.